# Using Subversion with intellij idea

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I installed TortoiseSVN 1.8 in my windows system.
I cannot seem to checkout from a repository using Intellij Idea 14.14

I configured the settings of Intellij idea to correctly give the path of the location of svn.exe

But upon checking out it says:

> Cannot checkout from svn: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Am i missing anything else?

Comment: Sounds like the path to your SVN tools is something like `C:\Program Files\` and it's either not properly quoted or the app doesn't know how to deal with spaces in paths.

Comment: That's what i thought but since i browsed to the location in intellij idea i thought it would figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Settings` -> `Version Control` -> `Subversion` and try setting "Use command line client:" to simply `svn` (no path).

Given that `svn.exe` is available in the path and can be executed via `svn` on a normal command line, this should work.